# Are unnecessary computations avoidable?

Tags: matlab, optimization, lazy-evaluation

I got an index-array `ind` of length `len` which is either `0` or `1`. I need results coming from a complex and time-intensive function `func` to be stored in a result-vector `res` (also length `len`). Input-vector is called `inp`.

I could do this via the two following ways:

```
% 1st way:
res = zeros(len,1);
res(ind) = func(inp);

% 2nd way:
res = ind .* func(inp);
```

My question for the 2<sup>nd</sup> one: for those entries where `ind` is `0`, does MATLAB evaluate `func()`? I hope not, because zero times anything else is zero, so it is a waste to evaluate `func`.

Comment: Answering your question: MATLAB evaluates `func` even if `ind` is zero.

Answer (score 3):

For those entries where ind is 0, your first option won't work because `res(ind)` will throw an error:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Anyway, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
allowed_indices = ind > 0;   % Logical indexing of valid indices
res = zeros(len,1);
res(allowed_indices) = func(inp(allowed_indices));
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably does, but this is very easy for you to test by making a test `func` that prints to the console and then make all of `ind` `0` and see if it prints anything (I'm sure it will, but I don't have MATLAB to check myself).

> I hoped no because zero times sth. else is zero

Not necessarily, what about `0*inf`? Or `0*NaN`?

If the point of your question is which is more efficient, test both using [`timeit`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html)